# Accessing root in anaconda prompt for windows

Tags: python, anaconda, root, conda

I want to run scripts beginning with conda command. But I get the following error:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required
 path.
  path: c:\C:\Users\SMA.D\.conda\environments.txt
```

As can be seen the first part of the path comes with an extra `c:\`. How can I access the root and run my commands from there in windows.

Know the command line is somthing like this:

```
(base) c:\conda create -n hw1 python=3.6
```

I can't even change the installed python version due to this error.

Comment: You probably installed anaconda with admin privileges

Comment: @MadPhysicist I didn't change anything in the installation procedure from its default except that I've chosen the checkbox to add anaconda to environmental variables.

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda is attempting to write to `c:\C:\Users\SMA.D\.conda\environments.txt` - this needs to be reconfigured, specifically, `c:\C:\` should be changed to `C:\`

Comment: Thank you for answering. How can I reconfigure anaconda?